# android notification display on the notification bar

Tags: android, notifications

I want to listen the nofication display event by through the android system, it means that I want to know whether the nofication has been displayed on the notification bar on the phone, and how can I get the target? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for notifying a notification

```
private void generateNotification(Context context) {

            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // notifytime = when;
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,
                    com.example.RegisterActivity.class);

            notifyIntent.putExtra("address", "Hello World");

            notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Hello World").setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setWhen(when);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationManager.notify((int) when, builder.build());
        }
```

there we can put notification id and we can check that notification id in NotificationManager